# Synchronous consumption on Node-RED & MQTT

Tags: asynchronous, mqtt, node-red

I am working on an orchestration system using Node-RED and MQTT.
I have decided to dissociate the event acquisition from the treatment. The main objective is to quickly push events on a queue and treat them soon as possible in real time.

The system operates like this :

1. I receive an event on an HTTP Rest API,
2. Push this event on an MQTT Topic,
3. On an another flow, listen and read events from the MQTT Topic,
4. Launch several actions/process from this event (up to 5/10 seconds).

But I am facing an issue: If I receive too quickly 2 related events, the second event could change the processing of the first event. To solve this, I would like to synchronize my event consumption/processing in order to keep them ordered.

MQTT QoS 2 messages will be delivered in order. How can I simply implement a synchronization paradigm in Node-RED ? Is it possible to avoid MQTT Client listening while processing an event ?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't turn the MQTT client off.

And no there is no concept of synchronisation, mainly because all NodeJS apps are purely single threaded so 2 things can't actually happen at once, tasks just yield normally when they get to something IO bound.

I'm not sure you actually gain anything receiving it via HTTP and then re-consuming it via MQTT.

If you want to queue the incoming events up you could use the delay node to rate limit the input to something you are sure the processing can manage. The rate limit option has 2 modes, one that drops messages and one the queues them,.

Comment: I'm using MQTT to queue received elements (through HTTP) as a resilience mechanism. The RATE limiter is not usable because it's based on time consumption and is not avoiding parallel processing.

Answer (score 0):

Place a simple message Q on output of MQTT client and get it to release next message by sending it trigger=true (or might be able to get it to release a message at a set rate).  I am still looking at these.
https://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-contrib-simple-message-queue

Answer (score 0):

Here is my proposal to solve the problem: https://flows.nodered.org/flow/3003f194750b0dec19502e31ca234847.

> Sync req/res REST API with async workers based on MQTT
>
> Example implements one REST API endpoint, one inject node for doing requests to that endpoint and two workers doing their job async.

It's still in progress so expect changes. Feel free to contact me and chat about this or other solutions for orchestration along with Node-RED.